# Use Fermat's Theorem to find al the roots of $3x^{98}+x^{19}+3$ in $\mathbb Z_7[x]$.

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Use Fermat's Theorem to find al the roots of $3x^{98}+x^{19}+3$ in $\mathbb Z_7[x]$.

I can't find the theorem in my book so I googled it and found that $a^{p-1}-1\equiv 0$ (mod $p$). So our $p=7$ because 7 is prime and $a=98$ and $a=19$ b/c 7 doesn't divide either. So: $98^{97}-1\equiv 0$ and $19^{18}-1\equiv 0$. How do I use these to find factors? Would it be like $x^{97}-1$ and $x^{18}-1$?

EDIT: I have done some more research and realized I should use $x^6\equiv 1$(mod$7$). So $3x^{98}+x^{19}+3\equiv 3x^{6*16+2}+x^{6*3+1}+3$, ie $3x^2+x+3$

Comment: The **roots** of $3x^{98}+x^{19}+3$ lie in $\mathbb{F}_7=\mathbb{Z}/(7\mathbb{Z})$ (or $\mathbb{F}_{7^2}$, or $\mathbb{F}_{7^3}$, ...), not in $\mathbb{Z}_7[x]$.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio I apologize this is how it was asked to me. I know $\mathbb Z_7$ is a field.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

Clearly, $(x,7)=1\implies x^6\equiv1\pmod7$

As $98\equiv2,19\equiv1\pmod6,$

$$3x^{98}+x^{19}+3\equiv3x^2+x+3\pmod7$$

which $\equiv3(x-1)^2$