# Find polynomials of degree $\leq 6$ in $\mathbb Z_7[x]$: $4x^{108} +6x^{101}-2x^{81}$

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Using Fermat's Theorem find polynomials of degree $\leq 6$ which determine the same function as the following polynomials in $\mathbb Z_7[x]$: $4x^{108} +6x^{101}-2x^{81}$ and $3x^{103}-x^{73}+3x^{55}-x^{25}$.

EDIT:
In $\mathbb Z_7[x], 4x^{108} +6x^{101}-2x^{81}\equiv 6x^5-2x^3$.
In $\mathbb Z_3[x], 4x^{2*54}+6x^{2*48+5}-2x^{2*39+3} = 6x^5-2x^3$. 
Thus for $p=3$ or in $\text{mod} 3$.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2518313/use-fermats-theorem-to-find-al-the-roots-of-3x98x193-in-mathbb-z-7/2518319#2518319

Comment: This doesn't answer the question with $\mathbb{Z}_4[x]$ tho

Comment: What did you learn from the answer to [your previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2518313/use-fermats-theorem-to-find-al-the-roots-of-3x98x193-in-mathbb-z-7/2518319#2518319)?

Comment: Oh wow I completely forgot that p needs to be prime. So I should use p=3 and $a^2\equiv 1$(mod $3$)

Answer (score 1):

For the first one, yes (7 is a prime). The second one is incorrect, $x^3 \neq 1 (mod\ 4)$ $\forall x\in\mathbb{Z}$, for example $2^3 = 8$ and $8 = 0 (mod\ 4)$. But we do know that $x^4 = x^{4*k}$ with $k\in\mathbb{N}$ still working with modulo 4. Hopefully you can now work this out!